# Running modules project in devserver using gcloud command

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, module, gcloud, devserver

I have created a project using maven with the following "layout"
- proj-ear
- module1-war
- module2-war

Running this with "mvn appengine:devserver" works just fine, both apps/modules starts and shows up in admin console. 
However, I am not able to run it with "mvn gcloud:run" (which I believe is necessary if/when I want to move a module to a managed vm?)

I get:
    ...

```
[INFO] INFO: Starting API server at: `http://localhost:50500`

[INFO] INFO: Starting module "module1" running at: `http://localhost:8080`

[INFO] INFO: Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore

...

[INFO] google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8081

[ERROR] Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1

...
```

Using mvn:run ends up in calling the actual "gcloud preview app run" command, so I dont think this is a maven problem.

Why is this happening and any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common family of error when running servers on a computer. The error is coming from the `wsgi_server` code, which is attempting to open a socket on port `8081`, I assume for `module2`. It fails, probably due to the port already being claimed by another process.

You can check which processes are listening on these ports using commands `netstat` for windows or `lsof -i` for linux/mac. Terminating any processes that are using ports your devserver will request (probably just a previous run of devserver) should allow the new devserver to bind on that port.